# Navigation & Tombstoning - Best Practices

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, tombstoning

I'm just learning about how to navigate between pages and tombstoning.  I'm wondering if anyone can point me to some good examples that not only show me the basics of how to use Navigation properly but also good examples of more complicated and advanced navigation issues?

- Some questions I have revolve around memory leaks when navigating to other pages and navigating back?
- Is there a close page call, once the page has done its job (I don't want an instance of it hanging around after I'm done with it)?
- Another question is how to I maintain state if the app gets tombstoned (still trying to wrap my head around that term).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no close page call, the OS automatically closes pages when they're backed out and releases used memory (so there should be no leaks here).

Some resources here that cover tombstoning and advanced navigation concepts.

[Understanding the Windows Phone Application Execution Model, Tombstoning, Launcher and Choosers, and Few More Things That Are on the Way – Part 1](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx), [Part 2](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/16/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-2.aspx), [Part 3](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/20/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-more-part-3.aspx)

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 1):

I like thinking about WP7 navigation like a simple browser that only have back button. The Naviation model is based on stack pattern (Last In First Out), need to get through all to get back to first page. This is not what PC user are used to but in mobile world is one of the best solution.
You have to stick to this model and never ever do "go to home page" button - your app will not pass the certification for sure(there are some workaround with excetions but I wouldnt recommend that).
A lot of pages can get the user pissed that's why a good idea is to have 3 to 5 pages max. For instance, first page user picks what he is going to do, next page is login page and then for more complex interface use panorama and pivot control.

To the simple browser model add cookies. When your browser load a page it sets a cookie with some information, next you close the browser and when you go back to the page it can get the previous state from that cookie. Tombstoning is very simailar. - [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-08-Taking-a-look-inside-Windows-Phone-Programming-Model-Architecture). Some more [info about tombstoning](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/egibson/windows-phone-7-jump-start-session-8-of-12-advanced-application-development-part-2)

> Some questions I have revolve around memory leaks when navigating to other pages and navigating back?

What do you mean by memory leaks? you are working in managed framework.

> Is there a close page call, once the page has done its job (I don't want an instance of it hanging around after I'm done with it)?

you do not have to do this. Page is destroyed everytime you go to the next page **unless** a thread is still working there.

> Another question is how to I maintain state if the app gets tombstoned (still trying to wrap my head around that term).

Basically it's up to develepor to manage this. It is not mandatory but gives a nice user experience.

Answer (score 1):

> Another question is how to I maintain state if the app gets tombstoned (still trying to wrap my head around that term).

Use Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into Columbus MVC framework for WP7 source code (http://columbus.codeplex.com/) that I have published recently. Columbus addresses both Navigation and Tombstoning (provides strongly typed navigation with history and View Models that can survive tombstoning).